# Qt6Quick in yocto

Tags: qml, yocto, qtquick2, bitbake, qt6

Is it possible to use QtQuick in yocto? (Or I missed something out)

I created simple coffee_6.2.0.bb recipe which uses demo from
`~/Qt/Examples/Qt-6.2.0/demos/coffee/`

But the error is:
Could NOT find Qt6Quick (missing: Qt6Quick_DIR

Recipe is quite simple:

```
.. Description and license stuff..

inherit qt6-cmake

include recipes-qt/qt6/qt6.inc

PROVIDES += "coffee"

FILES_${PN} += "${datadir}/${PN}"

do_install() {
  install -d ${D}${base_bindir}
  install ${B}/coffee ${D}${base_bindir}/coffee
}

SRC_URI = "file://${BP}.zip"
```

I am using http://code.qt.io/yocto/meta-qt6.git layer.

Comment: have you install all the necessary packages?

Comment: I think I have. qtbase and qtdeclarative are compiled installed trough DEPENDS += and I can also run examples of qtbase in the image if  not using coffe_6.2.0.bb.

Answer (score 1):

I faced a similar issue recently.
Adding `qtquick3d` as a dependency solved the issue for me:

```
DEPENDS += "qtbase qtquick3d qtdeclarative qtdeclarative-native"
```